# How to call a generic method?

Tags: java, generics

I have a method, `<T> void method(T element,Collection<T> list)`, I am able to call it as `method("A",list)`, where list can be `List<String>` or `List<Object>`

But fails if I call `method(new Object(),list)` where list is `List<String>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `T` needs to be the same in both cases. In the first case both are `Strings` - excellent. In the second one is `Object` and the other is `String` - not so good. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @RichardTingle My doubt is in first i am able to call with String,Object  why is that?

Comment: Hm, that is an intersting point. One second

Comment: @Zoyd I introduced no errors in my previous edit. The `<T>` was hidden by the formatting of the question but it was there. As it stands, now that you removed the generic type parameter, this code does not compile.

Comment: @ZouZou My bad, I wasn't paying enough attention. I see you rolled backed, so that's fixed.

Comment: Ok, its because `T` is `Object` in `method("A",list)` where list is `List<Object>`. Whereas with `method(new Object(),list)` where list is `List<String>` there is no T that can simultaneously satisfy both. But that isn't quite formalised enough for me to put it as an answer

Comment: @Zoyd No problems, I'm not sure if you could see it in the edit history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the method `<T> void method(T element,Collection<T> list)`

When using a generic method an appropriate T is found. If no such T exists then a compile time exception is thrown.

### `method("A",new List<String>)`

- First argument "A" T can be anything between `Object` and `String`
- Second argument T can be anything between `String` and `String` since the generic argument is explicitly defined by `List<String>`

T is `String`

### `method("A",new List<Object>)`

- First argument "A" T can be anything between `Object` and `String`
- Second argument T can be anything between `Object` and `Object` since the generic argument is explicitly defined by `List<Object>`

T is `Object`

### `method(new Object(),new List<String>)`

- First argument `new Object()` T can be anything between `Object` and `Object`
- Second argument T can be anything between `String` and `String` since the generic argument is explicitly defined by `List<String>`

No T exists that simultaneously satisfies both

Answer (score 4):

This example shows, that your `List<String>` is not `List<Object>` even while `String` IS-A `Object`. You should use generic wildcards:

```
<T> void method(T element,Collection<? extends T> list)
```

Comment: That is fine, reading forth i came to know this but still doubtful over why no error on calling with String,Object as mentioned in first case?

Comment: Because a `String` can always be treated as an `Object`, because `String` extends `Object`.

Comment: Could you please confirm it, if i call method(String,List<Object>) then T is Object, when method(Object, List<String) here T is String right? i conclude so, but confused... is it right?

Comment: The first case - yes, you're right. In the second - no, just look into this expression: there T would be Object and Collection <? extends T> would be Collection <String>: String = ? extends Object is correct.

Comment: Which version of method are you using?  If `method` is defined as `<T> void method(T element, Collection<T> list)`, then there's no possible value of `T` that works when you're calling with `Object, List<String>`.